# No TLS handshake from IIS 10

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2016

I have an IIS 10 server running on windows server 2016. To make sure everything is up and running ive just been using the default website with the 'iisstart' page as a test. I can hit the site over port 80, no problem. Port 443, however is proving more difficult.

The cert is a wildcard SSL cert from Go Daddy, and ive no reason to think there any problems with it (its installed ok, the certificate chain looks good, and there were no problems applying it to the site).

Running wireshark on the server, i can see it get the 'Client hello' message, but the server never seems to generate the corresponding server hello.

[image]

Both client and server are TLS1.2 capable, and the server has TLS1.2 enabled.

Any suggestions what i might be missing, or where to start looking?

Comment: Where did you make the pcap? Did you check on the server side that the server a) gets the ClientHello and b) really does not send the ServerHello back? Because if you just looked at the client site it might be that there is a firewall between client and server which is either blocking the ClientHello or the ServerHello..

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html See what SSL Diagnostics reports.